# CSS offset properties and static position

Tags: css, positioning

Are offset properties (left, top, bottom, right) only for non-static positions?

Can they be applied to a statically positioned element? If so, what are the differences from
applying them to non-statically positioned elements?

Comment: Those offset properties only apply on positioned elements (elements that have the position property set to absolute, fixed or relative).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to **offset** an element it's position has to be `position:relative`

the co-ordinates, `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` serve different purposes depending on if the element is relatively or absolutely positioned.

**When is an element *offset* as opposed to moved?**

when you actually offset using `position: relative;` the element is not removed from the flow, and indeed the space that the element would have taken up if it had remained static (the default) is still reserved for it, therefore you have just offset it from it's original position. Any element following it will appear where it would have done even if you hadn't offset it's predecessor - like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/D7p3k/)

**Moving, not offsetting**

If however you actually want to move an element, then it needs to be removed from the flow, so there is no space reserved for it, and then that's when you use `position:absolute;` or fixed.. that is the difference

**Summary**

- `static` is the default, and you just use margins to move it around, it will ignore co-ordinates and z-index
- `relative` is reserved space, co-ordinates will offset it from it's original space
- `absolute` will remove the element from the flow and the co-ordinates will be calculated according to it's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details), which is the nearest relatively positioned ancestor (or the `body` element if no relatively positioned ancestors exist)
- `fixed` does not have a containing block, i.e. you can't specify which element it should be positioned in relation to, it will just fix itself in relation to the viewport

and finally an element will not accept a `z-index` if it's position is the default of static, so `position: relative;` without any co-ordinates applied is *similar* to `static`, but it is useful for z-indexing and being a containing block for absolutely positioned elements

Comment: I understand absolute now. Im gonna let this one sink in before trying to understand the rest.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to apply them to `position: static` elements, as they are static.

To *shift* a static element over by a certain amount, you can change it's `position` property to `position: relative;`.

Now, you can shift it around with `top`, `left`, etc.

There exist a few more types of `position`, namely `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`.

`fixed` makes the element fixed to the screen and it's unaffected by scrolling, so it's as if it's stuck to the computer monitor. Setting its `top`, etc. sets the position.

`absolute` makes the element positioned relative to the document and ignore all layout rules. Setting it's position sets where it is positioned on the document.

Comment: you probably meant position:static; position:relative; display doesn't have those values...  But what happens if i assign offset property to statically positioned element?? nothing at all??

Comment: You can change it to `position: relative` and then the offsets will shift it around. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

They can be applied to absolute and fixed position elements, which are essentially the same but fixed always uses the document window as its anchor. You can also apply them to relatively positioned elements in which case they are an offset from what is best described as the default inline positioning.